# regex only detects illegal characters at end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using regex in Javascript to verify that an entry in a textbox only contains legal characters. My expression is:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+@-]$/.test(value)
```

This correctly identifies cases like "~~~" or "4389sdf~~~", but if there are any legal characters following, such as "~~~bvv" then it gets a pass.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `$` at the end of the regular expression explicitly means, "match at the end of the string".

Comment: ..Or `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+@-]+$/` if you want *at least one* symbol

Comment: If these `a-zA-Z0-9._%+@-` chars are *allowed*, you need `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+@-]*$/` or `/^[a-z0-9._%+@-]*$/i`.